# Error when sending signed mail in Evolution

Tags: evolution

When I try to send a mail in Evolution, I get the following error:

> Could not create message.
>
> Because "Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user. (-8172) - Cannot add MS SMIMEEncKeyPrefs attribute", you may need to select different mail options

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by marking the user certificate to use as "trusted peer" with certutil.

First install certutil if not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3-tools
```

Then find the certificate nickname with

```
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L
```

For me this nick is "Andreas Neustifter", it is different for you. Finally I marked this (my) certificate as trusted peer with

```
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -M -n "Andreas Neustifter" -t Pu,Pu,Pu
```

(Again, the nickname (given as option -n) is different for you...)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!  This was helpful to me.  However, it took me a while to discover that in my case (Ubuntu 16.04) the Evolution database was located in:
`$HOME/.local/share/evolution`

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04: `for i in $(certutil -d $HOME/.local/share/evolution -L|grep '@'|awk '{ print $1 }'); do certutil -d $HOME/.local/share/evolution -M -n "$i" -t P,P,P; done`